# Center the individual Menu Items within a Horizontal Menu

Tags: html, css

I want to center the Individual Menu items within this Horizontal CSS menu (obtained from purecssmenu.com).

They are currently floating to the left and I want them to be centered

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="pureCssMenu pureCssMenum">
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Menu1</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#"><span>Menu2</span><![if gt IE 6]></a><![endif]><!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul class="pureCssMenum">
            <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
            <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#"><span>Submenu2</span><![if gt IE 6]></a><![endif]><!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
            <ul class="pureCssMenum">
                <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
                <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Submenu4</a></li>
                <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Submenu5</a></li>
            </ul>
            <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
        </ul>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#"><span>Menu3</span><![if gt IE 6]></a><![endif]><!--[if lte IE 6]><table><tr><td><![endif]-->
        <ul class="pureCssMenum">
            <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
            <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
        </ul>
        <!--[if lte IE 6]></td></tr></table></a><![endif]--></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Menu4</a></li>
        <li class="pureCssMenui"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="#">Menu5</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The complete HTML markup and CSS is available at this JsFiddle
   http://jsfiddle.net/28X9v/

The solution should be cross browser compatible and should atleast work in ie7/8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is the answer you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/28X9v/5/

```
<span>....</span>
```

is used for aligning in the code . That's it.

Comment: Can you fix the link and add the jsfiddle. I will accept your response.

Comment: Just want to point out that @Niranth's solution was built on top of Era's suggestions. Thanks guys!

Comment: I just noticed that with your change, IE7 is rendering the  horizontal menu as a vertical menu. Any suggestions? Works fine in IE8+ and Chrome

Answer (score 0):

Remove float from your `li's` : **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/28X9v/1/)**

```
ul.pureCssMenu, ul.pureCssMenu ul {text-align:center;}
ul.pureCssMenu li { display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: It disrupts the alignment and makes the menu messy

Comment: @Era - Thanks for your response. I think what you are suggesting makes sense but it does mess up the vertical alignment. Any suggestions on how to fix it.

Comment: thats because of that span.. this is not complete css i guess.. and images are also not there.. this can be solve by adding span to every text in `LI` .. hope i am clear.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/28X9v/4/ .check it.. perfect alignment.
@Era : U missed to add span to MENU4 and MENU5.. I added it

Comment: @niranth And what about the submenu alignment Menu2 -> submenu2 ?

Comment: @Mustafasabir :  sorry i missed it in that fiddle..
check here : http://jsfiddle.net/28X9v/5/

Comment: @NiranthReddy & Era: Thanks for your suggestions. I think this comes really close.

Comment: @NiranthReddy You are too quick. Thanks for helping me out. Thanks to everyone (Era, Mustafa, Niranth and ကစၥပ နဒီ) for your responses. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

hey view testing this code

```
.pureCssMenum li > ul.pureCssMenum li{
  float: left;
 }
.pureCssMenum li > ul.pureCssMenum > li > ul.pureCssMenum{

   position:absolute;
     top:40px;
  }
.pureCssMenum li > ul.pureCssMenum > li > ul.pureCssMenui li{
   float:none;
   position:relative;

 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kisspa/LdXU5/

Comment: Thanks for your response. But unfortunately this is not what I was going for.

Answer (score 0):

Make the following changes to your css

To increase the submenu width to accomodate right shifting

```
ul.pureCssMenu ul {
    width:110px;
}
```

and change the margin values to shift menu items to right

```
ul.pureCssMenu li {
    display:block;
    margin:2px 0px 2px 18px;
    font-size:0px;
}
```

You can change the last param of margin property to shift the elements more towards right.

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/28X9v/3/

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is a good suggestion but it still doenst completely center it. Maybe if I tweak the width and margin values, I can get it to work.

Comment: change the 18px to 20px, and the 110px to 115px